# Recognise MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE when finger is on screen before resuming Activity

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I'm trying to move Views from one Activity to another (after LongClick). If the second Activity pops up, the user should be able to move the View around on the screen.

Sadly, Android seems not to send a MotionEvent if the user decides to keep his finger on the screen during change of the activity. My onTouchListener will not be called until the user lifts his finger and presses again. I already tried to send an MotionEvent.Action_Down to my View to trigger the Listener, but this doesn't help receiving the Action_Move-events as I had hoped. Any ideas out there?

Here's my recent OnResume:

```
@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if (getIntent().hasExtra("PluginAdded")){
        Screen screen = Screen.getInstance(this);
        String pluginName = getIntent().getStringExtra("PluginName");
        Point fingerPos = new Point(getIntent().getIntExtra("FingerPosX", 0), getIntent().getIntExtra("FingerPosY", 0));
        PluginManager pluginManager = new PluginManager(this);
        Plugin plugin = pluginManager.getPlugin(APIConstants.PLUGIN_STRING + "." + pluginName, true);
        int pluginSize = plugin.getSize();
        PluginContainer container = new PluginContainer(this, plugin, 1, fingerPos, screen.getSlots(), screen.getActualSmallestSize());
        final FrameLayout containerView = addContainerView(container);

        //HERE'S THE RELEVANT PART***********************
        OnTouchListener fingerMoved = new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getActionMasked() == (MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)){
                    containerView.setX(event.getRawX());
                    containerView.setY(event.getRawY());
                }
            return true;
            }
        };
        containerView.setOnTouchListener(fingerMoved);
        //Doesn't help at all
        MotionEvent eventActionDown = MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis()-1, SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, fingerPos.x, fingerPos.y, 0);
        containerView.dispatchTouchEvent(eventActionDown);
        eventActionDown.recycle();
        //*************************************************
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're moving between activities, you'll have to store the touch event status in a global variable, that can be accessed between both activities.

With that, you'll need a *separate* Application-context class, like so:

```
import android.app.Application;

public class GlobalVars extends Application {
    public static Boolean mouseDown = false;
}
```

The variable can be accessed like so:

```
final GlobalVars globs = (GlobalVars)context.getApplicationContext();
globs.mouseDown = true;
```

So with that in mind, this should be what your onTouchListener might look like:

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v,MotionEvent event) {
        final GlobalVars globs = (GlobalVars)context.getApplicationContext();
        switch(event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                globs.mouseDown = true;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                globs.mouseDown = false;
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

This will have to be combined with your x and y functions, if those are in your first activity.

Hope this helps